# Javascript - Save Geolocation Coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How can i save the coordinates in localstorage so that it shouldn't ask the users every time to allow GPS or Location and a button to clear the localstorage value so it can again ask for coordinates?

FYI: 
I am using [Praytimes JS](http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js) to display Muslim prayer times but for each location i have to manually add latitude & longitude of that location.

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var x = document.getElementById("currentlocation");

  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    $('#currentlocation').html("Geocoder failed");
}

  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();



  }

  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
        if (results[1]) {
         //formatted address
         $('#currentlocation').html(results[0].formatted_address);
        //find country name
             for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

            //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        $('#currentlocation').html(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          $('#currentlocation').html("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        $('#currentlocation').html("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>

<p id="currentlocation"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadTable(position) {
        prayTimes.setMethod('MWL'); 
        var date = new Date(); // today
        var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
        var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

        var html = '<table id="timetable">';
        html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
        for(var i in list)  {
            html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
            html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
        }
        html += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(loadTable);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define an object with the informations of the coordinates:

```
var coordinatesObject = 
{
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
}
```

Save it in the local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('coordinates', 
JSON.stringify(coordinatesObject));
```

Get it:

```
let objFromLocalStorage = 
localStorage.getItem('coordinates');
```

Comment: can you please provide me an example with my above code...where should i paste the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var CACHED_POSITION = "CACHED_POSITION";

var x = document.getElementById("currentlocation");

var geocoder;

(function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        try {
            var position = JSON.parse(window.localStorage[CACHED_POSITION]);
            if (position) {
                successFunction(position);
                return;
            }
        } catch (e) {

        }
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
})();

//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    window.localStorage[CACHED_POSITION] = JSON.stringify(position);

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;//Save to cache
    codeLatLng(lat, lng);
}
```

Comment: `window.localStorage[CACHED_POSITION] = JSON.stringify(position);`
when you are using square brackets notation you have to use quotes like `["CACHED_POSITION"]`, why you didn't use setItem method ? this way will not insert the item into the local storage!

Comment: window.localStorage.XXX=window.localStorage["XXX"]=window.localStorage.getItem("XXX")